# Adding features to component

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I see the following code (ExtJs 3.0),and have a doubt.

```
Ext.ns('Dummy.');
Dummy.RevEvents = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, 
{
    getData:function(){
    this.deletedRows=[];
    this.newRows=[];
    ......  
    },
    deletedRows:[],
    newRows:[],
    addEditableRow: function(){
    ...
    },
    initComponent:function(){   
        var revEvents_config = {
            autoScroll:true         
             ...
             ,listeners: {afterrender: function(t) {    
            ...
            }}
            ,buttons:[              
            ...
            ]
        }
    Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, revEvents_config));
    Dummy.RevEvents.superclass.initComponent.call(this, revEvents_config);
    },..    
});
Ext.reg('REVEVTS', Dummy.RevEvents);
```

1.What is the intention of passign over the config to the initcomponent of superclass?
Hasnt it already been applied on the Apply?
2.Is this the recommended of adding listeners and controls to a component?

Answer (score 0):

The code was probably written by someone who didn't quite understand what was happening.

`Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, revEvents_config));`

This will #1/ override the component's `initialConfig` with the component's default settings `revEvents_config` and then #2/ apply the result configuration onto the component. I assume the developer reversed the intended use: #1/ `initialConfig` is readonly and #2/ it makes no sense to override the component's configuration with some default settings.

The standard way of adding listeners to an extended object in Ext 3 is to do the following:

```
/**
 * @class MyNamespace.MyComponent
 * @extends OtherNamespace.OtherComponent
 * <p>Some comments here to be built by jsduck</p>
 */
MyNamespace.MyComponent = Ext.extend(OtherNamespace.OtherComponent, {
    defaultProp1 : defaultVal1,
    defaultProp2 : defaultVal2,

    // we get here AFTER the component's properties have been initialized by
    // the Ext.extend method.
    initComponent : function(){
        // call OtherNamespace.OtherComponent's initComponent
        MyNamespace.MyComponent.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
        // add custom events to the existing ones from OtherNamespace.OtherComponent
        this.addEvents('event1', 'event2', ...);
        // add any logic pertaining to the resulting config from Ext.extend
        if(this.defaultProp1 === ...){ ... }
    },

    otherPublicMethod: function(){
        ...
    },

    otherPublicMethodThatOverridesSuperClass: function(){
        // do we need to call the super method?
        // if yes:
        MyNamespace.MyComponent.superclass.otherPublicMethodThatOverridesSuperClass.call(this);
        ...
    }

});
Ext.reg('mycustomtype', MyNamespace.MyComponent);
```

Comment: So ,would Ext.apply(this,revEvents_config) be the correct approach then?Would it ensure that any 'extended' configuration is added over and above the initial config;rather than overwriting it.

Comment: No. The application of the passed configuration to the object is already being done in the Ext.extend.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure what the intention is, passing the config to the `initComponent` will not do anything.  The Panel's `initComponent` does not take any arguments.  Messing with the `initialConfig` is asking for undefined behavior.  The default `Component` constructor will take the config passed in, apply it to the current instance and save it off as `initialConfig`.  There are little to no arguments for modifying the initialConfig or even looking at its values.
2. The recommended way of adding listeners would be to call `on` or `addListener` in the `initComponent`.  This will allow for extending classes or instances to add listeners without overwriting them.  For example `new Dummy.RevEvents({listeners: destroy ..})` will overwrite your `afterrender` listener in your example which is probably not wanted.